# Puppet ERROR: "Cannot find data item in any Hiera data file and no default supplied at on node localhost" even though it's right there

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

My hiera.yaml looks like this:

```
---
:backends: yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: "%{settings::manifestdir}/hieradata"
:hierarchy:
  - epmpi
  - common
```

And my yaml file named epmp is placed in hieradata/epmp.yaml

I can't seem to figure out why it isn't picking up the data values.

Answer (score 2):

Typo in your hiera.yaml?

```
:hierarchy:
  - epmpi
```

should be

```
:hierarchy:
  - epmp
```